# Using apparmor for symbolic links to an executable file

Tags: apparmor

I have a script that runs in *cron* using **wget**. I want to restrict its permissions using AppArmor. Ideally, I would like to create a symbolic link at **/home/user/wget -> /usr/bin/wget** and add an AppArmor profile for **/home/user/wget**. But this doesn't work, the AppArmor profile still applies to **/usr/bin/wget**. How can I better implement this?

I want to emphasize that I do not want to use a separate bash script and pass parameters to it, as it doesn't suit my needs.